# How to enable window maximization on Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

The maximize button on my Electron app is grayed out/disabled. I didn't do this in my code and I am using Windows 11.

This is my code:

```js
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        backgroundMaterial: 'acrylic',
        resizable: true,
        minimizable: true,
        maximizable: true,
        darkTheme: true
    });

    /* rest of code here */
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
});
```

I tried setting resizable and maximizable to true but nothing worked.